# How do I read Javascript Closure Syntax?

Tags: javascript, syntax, closures

Based on some code in a lecture by Doug Crockford, I've created this.

```
var isAlphaUser = (function() {
    alert("Forming Alpha User List");
    let AlphaUsers = {
        1234: true,
        5678: true
    };

    return function(id){
        alert("Checking Alpha Users:",id); 
        return AlphaUsers[id];};
}());

alert("starting");
alert(isAlphaUser(1234));
alert(isAlphaUser(5678));
alert(isAlphaUser(3456));
```

which gives me this:

```
Forming Alpha User List
starting
Checking Alpha Users: 1234
true
Checking Alpha Users: 5678
true
Checking Alpha Users: 3456
undefined
```

Which is quite cool, as it does the expensive setup once only, and every further call is a cheap check.

However, I can't *decipher* the code that does this. Specifically, I can't understand why I need the "()" at the end of the function declaration.

Can somebody explain how this syntax is working?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

`()` calls a function.  `function() { }` defines a function.  Appending `()` right after immediately calls it<sup>1</sup>, and the result (also an anonymous function) is assigned to `isAlphaUser`.

The `function() { ... }()` pattern is frequently used to isolate variables to an inner scope, so those variables don't become part of the global scope.

In this case, this is what happens:

1. An anonymous function is run, defining a variable `AlphaUsers` inside that scope.
2. That function returns another function that takes 1 parameter. This function is a closure to which the `AlphaUsers` variable becomes bound (in other words, available).  This function checks if the parameter passed in is contained in `AlphaUsers` (actually, it returns the item at that index, which is just a boolean).
3. The return value is assigned to a variable `isAlphaUser`.
4. Since `isAlphaUser` is now a function, it can be called to see if the parameter is contained in the `AlphaUsers` variable, but no direct access to `AlphaUsers` is available in the global scope (it become a sort of private variable).

---

<sup>1 — **Note**: As cwolves mentioned in the comments, beware that while `()` appended directly after the `}` works in this case, it is only because in this case the function definition is a *function expression*.  If `function` is the first word on the line, the line becomes a *function declaration*, and that is all that line can do, the function is **not** anonymous (it will require a name, otherwise it's a syntax error) and cannot be called immediately inline.  See [Function Declarations vs. Function Expressions](http://javascriptweblog.wordpress.com/2010/07/06/function-declarations-vs-function-expressions/) for more info.</sup>

Comment: FYI, this will not work on functions declared like : `function foo(){ ... }()`.  The function needs to be inline either by wrapping it with `()` or by setting it to a variable.

Comment: Ah, so it's *executing* the originally defined function immediately. That's cool.

Comment: @cwolves Thanks!  Note appended to clarify.

Answer (score 1):

The () at the end of the code is separate from the closure issue. By wrapping your function in parens and adding the () at the end you are creating an anonymous function that is run immediately with whatever arguments you pass into ().

Answer (score 1):

> Specifically, I can't understand why I need the "()" at the end of the
>   function declaration.

It creates **self-invoking** function, in other words, the function is executed as soon as it is parsed.

It is basically same thing when you call a function by suffixing it with `()` like:

```
myfunc();   // call this func
```

Answer (score 0):

The top-level anonymous function returns the function that the isAlphasUser varaible refers to.

You need to call the top-level function, to get the inner-function reference.

Think of it like this, the outer anonymous function is a function factory, i.e., it returns a function.

In order to use any function (even one that returns a function) you must call it.